# How to access an arraylist from one rule to another in DROOLS

Tags: drools

This is the java file that is the rule engine
RuleRunner.java

```
public class RuleRunner {
KieSession kSession = null;

public RuleRunner() {
}

/**
 * Method that executes all the rules specified in rule file
 * 
 * @param rules
 * @param facts
 */
public void runRules(String[] rules, String[] values) {

    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieResources kieResources = kieServices.getResources();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();

    for (String ruleFile : rules) {
        Resource resource = kieResources.newClassPathResource(ruleFile);
        kieFileSystem.write(
                "src/main/resources/com/skills421/examples/drools6_0/"
                        + ruleFile, resource);
    }

    KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);

    kb.buildAll();
    if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Level.ERROR)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n"
                + kb.getResults().toString());
    }

    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository
            .getDefaultReleaseId());

    kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
    for (String value : values){
    kSession.insert(value);
    }
    kSession.fireAllRules();


}
```

}

This is Main.java which integrates the drl file and rule engine

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Creating the rule and specifying the rule file
    RuleRunner runner = new RuleRunner();



    String[] rules = { "test1.drl"};
    String[] values={"creditcard","personal_status","male single"};
    //Object[] facts = { new CreditCard("male single",25,">=7")};


    runner.runRules(rules,values);

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ms"); 
}
```

}

I am new to DROOLS.This is my .drl file

```
dialect "mvel"
/*
*This rule picks people with good credit record and an employment history      
of more than 7 years
*/

rule "Credit Card employment and class check"
when 
passList : ArrayList()
$creditCard : CreditCard() from passList
eval($creditCard.get_class() == "good" && $creditCard.getEmployment() ==    
">=7")

then 
passList = new  ArrayList();
passList.add($creditCard);

end  

dialect "java"

rule "passList check"
 when 
  eval( true )
 then
   System.out.println("passList size2....");
end
```

I want to pass the calculated value of passList from rule1 to rule2.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is *very* far from the way Drools can be used. Please don't post code - describe your Java class(es) and the problem, i.e., what should be checked and done if a check succeeds or fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My rule runner essentially fires a rule to a datastore and retrieves records as an arraylist.We check a condition in the list whether the class is good and the employment is more than 7 years.We only add the objects that matches to the second arrayList.I want to check the newly calculated arraylist in another rule.I am looking for a way to pass the arraylist to the second rule

Comment: Is it possible to declare a local variable for the arraylist in the first rule and then send it to the second rule

Comment: This isn't going to work at all. You insert three String objects `("creditcard", "personal_status", "male single")` but your rule refers to an `ArrayList` containing `CreditCard` objects. - You cannot assign a new value to a bound variable, as you have it in the first rule (`passList`). There is no way to pass a variable from one rule to the next.

Comment: Would a global variable or an insert help to make the ArrayList accessible through the rules

Comment: This is what I want to achieve: Rule1 computes the list of credit card holders whose personal _status is male single,In Rule two I want to compute creditcard holders whose personal_status is male single and age is 25. Instead of making a database hit everytime I thought it might be good to insert the arraylist from one rule on to the next.

Comment: You should insert CreditCard facts (not Strings, not ArrayLists) and write straightforward rules. There is no "database hit" as there is no "database" (as far as I can see).

Comment: I haven't added the database code..It connects with Apache Hive.

Comment: I added a global variable and was able to pass the value through out.Thanks again for the suggestions.I mostly followed your answers on all the other questions for the whole thing.Much appreciated.